# Custom icon doesn't appear

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm using Electron, with `electron-forge`. The app works fine, but the custom icon I've added doesn't appear. I still have the default Electron icon.

I have carefully followed the official documentation.

- I created 16x16, 32x32, 128x128, 256x256 and 512x512 png icons, generated an `icon.icns` set with `iconutil`, an `icon.ico` for Window and an `icon.png` for Linux.
- I've added all of them at the root of the project inside an `icon` folder, and added their path to my `forge.config`:

```js
import type { ForgeConfig } from "@electron-forge/shared-types";
import { MakerSquirrel } from "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel";
import { MakerZIP } from "@electron-forge/maker-zip";
import { MakerDeb } from "@electron-forge/maker-deb";
import { MakerRpm } from "@electron-forge/maker-rpm";
import { MakerDMG } from "@electron-forge/maker-dmg";
import { MakerWix } from "@electron-forge/maker-wix";
import { WebpackPlugin } from "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack";
import { mainConfig } from "./webpack.main.config";
import { rendererConfig } from "./webpack.renderer.config";
import path from "path";

const config: ForgeConfig = {
   packagerConfig: {
       icon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon"),
   },
   rebuildConfig: {},
   makers: [
      new MakerSquirrel({
         setupIcon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon", "icon.ico"),
      }),
      new MakerZIP({}, ["darwin"]),
      new MakerRpm({
         options: {
            icon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon", "icon.png"),
         },
      }),
      new MakerDeb({
         options: {
            icon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon", "icon.png"),
         },
      }),
      new MakerDMG({
         icon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon", "icon.icns"),
      }),
      new MakerWix({
         icon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon", "icon.ico"),
      }),
    ],
    plugins: [
        new WebpackPlugin({
           mainConfig,
             renderer: {
              config: rendererConfig,
              entryPoints: [
               {
                html: "./src/index.html",
                js: "./src/renderer.ts",
                name: "main_window",
                preload: {
                js: "./src/preload.ts",
               },
            },
          ],
        },
     }),
   ],
};

export default config;
```

I have also added the path to `main.ts`:

```js
const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    icon: path.join(process.cwd(), "icon", "icon.png"),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });
```

I also ran the `make` command.

The app compiles without any problem. But when I click on the `.dmg` file, I only see the 16x16 icon at the top of the window. The main icon is still the default's one. When running the app locally, I also never have my custom icon in the app menu.

How to fix this?